# Attach link to the reference section

Tags: hyperref

I want to add link in the reference but link is not showing in PDF. why?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}        

\title{{\bf Your Research Title}}
\author{Your Name }     
\date{December 17, 2013}                    
%
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
You have to write the abstract here.
\end{abstract}  
%
\tableofcontents

%
\section{Introduction}
Albert Einstein (/ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; German: [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[2][3] While best known for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation"),[4] he received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect".[5] The latter was pivotal in establishing quantum theory.
Near the beginning of his career, Einstein thought that Newtonian mechanics was no longer enough to reconcile the laws of classical mechanics with the laws of the electromagnetic field. This led to the development of his special theory of relativity. He realized, however, that the principle of relativity could also be extended to gravitational fields, and with his subsequent theory of gravitation in 1916, he published a paper on the general theory of relativity. He continued to deal with problems of statistical mechanics and quantum theory, which led to his explanations of particle theory and the motion of molecules. He also investigated the thermal properties of light which laid the foundation of the photon theory of light. In 1917, Einstein applied the general theory of relativity to model the large-scale structure of the universe.[6]

%
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{1} Aiolfi, M., & Favero, C.A. (2002). Model Uncertainty; Thick Modeling and the Predictability of Stock Returns. Bocconi University, Mimeo.

    \bibitem{12}Detry, P.J. en Gregiore, P. (2001). Other evidences of the predictive power of technical analysis: The moving averages rules on European indexes. EFMA Conference: Lugano. \url{<http://ssrn.com/abstract=269802>}.
    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{document}
\end{document}
```

**I have no problem in pdf output but I want  the html link in the pdf.**

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The `&` which should be `\&`, as it stands you get an error. Your snippet, when inserted into a minimal document, *does* produce a link in the PDF, so a complete example is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above code you'll get an error message saying that `\url` is undefined. You need to load a package that defines that command, such as `url` or `hyperref`. The latter will also create clickable hyperlinks of references, citations and URLs.

A couple of other notes:

- Replace the `&` with `\&` in the first bibliography entry. The ampersand is an active character used to separate columns in tables, to print an `&` in the PDF you need to escape it with a backslash.
- Don't use `\bf`, that syntax is deprecated. Use either `{\bfseries text}` or `\textbf{text}`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
- Are `[1]`, `[2]` etc. citations? In that case, you're not citing the bibliography the intended way. If you write e.g.

  ```
  \bibitem{einstein}
  Albert  (1904), \emph{Relatively clever stuff}
  ```

  in your bibliography, then you can cite that with `\cite{einstein}`. You use the same word in the `\cite` that is in the argument to the `\bibitem`.

  This way you make sure that the citation always is to the correct number. The bibitems are numbered automatically, and  `\cite` prints the corresponding number. (Two compilation runs is necessary.)
- Do you really want `<>` to surround the URL?

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{url}
% or you can use hyperref, which will also give clickable links in the PDF
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{aiolfi,detry}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{aiolfi} Aiolfi, M., \& Favero, C.A. (2002). Model Uncertainty; Thick Modeling and the Predictability of Stock Returns. Bocconi University, Mimeo.

    \bibitem{detry}Detry, P.J. en Gregiore, P. (2001). Other evidences of the predictive power of technical analysis: The moving averages rules on European indexes. EFMA Conference: Lugano. \url{http://ssrn.com/abstract=269802}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```